# Bootstrap Modal Change Width Programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I need to change the width of the modal programmatically, either through jquery or vanilla javascript.

Here are what I have:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-popup" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document" id="modal_dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
                <h3 class="modal-title pull-left" id="action_title">My Title</h3>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body text-center">My Body</div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close Window</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I cannot seem to work it with:

```
function popUpModal()
{  
   $('#modal-popup').modal('show');
   $('.modal-content').css('width','99%');  
   console.log('it is firing!');  
}
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Can you post the code where the function is called?

Comment: you should use `.modal-dialog` selector to set the width, not `.modal-content` . Usually modal-content will always expand full to its parent

Comment: @DucHong - apologies for posting the wrong code but I also have tried it with .modal-dialog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `max-width` of the `.modal-dialog` to 99%.  The modal content width is already a percentage of the modal-dialog.

```js
function popUpModal()
{  
   $('#modal-popup').modal('show');
   $('.modal-dialog').css('max-width','99%');  
   console.log('it is firing!');  
}

popUpModal();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-popup" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document" id="modal_dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
                <h3 class="modal-title pull-left" id="action_title">My Title</h3>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body text-center">My Body</div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close Window</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```